# SSL Certificates Usage for Kafka format using AZURE Event Hub

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, ssl-certificate, azure-eventhub

With KAFKA one can use SSL certificates. I am familiar with this approach https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-biz-automation/20.0.x?topic=emitter-preparing-ssl-certificates-kafka and that a REST API producer or JAVA program producer can implement this as well for writing KAFKA topics.

From the AZURE docs on Event Hub I cannot determine if, when sending a message to Event Hub with KAFKA API approach, whether this is also possible. I find the stuff hard to follow on AZURE.

I see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview, but:

- The section on Shared Access Signature (SAS) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview#shared-access-signature-sasstating SASL_SSL is that the same as SSL certificates
- And what does PLAIN mean?

Note this all pertains to a small account in AZURE with no AD Grouping applied.

My take is that SASL_SSL amounts to the same as SSL that I note at the top of the article and that no AD Groups are needed. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use SSL certificates to authenticate to the Kafka Endpoint of Azure Event Hub. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview#security-and-authentication) for the two possible auth options:

> Azure Event Hubs provides multiple options to authorize access to your secure resources.
>
> - OAuth 2.0
> - Shared access signature (SAS)

The latter is basically a password. SASL_SSL is just the protocol and you use it no matter which of the two options you choose. The connection must always be made with SSL encryption enabled but that is different than using certs for auth.

Comment: Well it's more about the producers as opposed to end point. Our security architect felt this was an option, but I cannot see it.

Comment: the auth options are the same for producers and consumers

Comment: OAUTH needs AZURE AD. We do not want that. I am pretty disappointed. I think just a password is not good enough. Do I need to consider Confluent on AZURE that would allow that?

Comment: if you need a "true" Kafka platform, you can use Confluent on Azure, yes. Or you run Kafka on HDinsight. However, you could also look into locking down your Event Hub on a networking layer. Then using SAS tokens should still be ok for your security folks. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/network-security

Comment: I take it you mean IP Firewall here. A little annoying as I was hoping to use things that are standard.

Comment: not sure what you mean. IP filtering / IP firewall is a native part of the Event Hub service. you just need to configure it

Comment: Relates also to other question. I am reading up on SAS tokens now.  Forgive my ignorance.